# Реализация поиска по ключу json поля mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

Нужна помощь с реализацией поиска по ключу json поля mysql.

Входные данные: массив названий ключей(строка)

Выходные данные: все записи с mysql таблицы, которые содержат в поле
copmetence(json формат), входные ключи.

Примеры:
1.Получаем массив - ["test"]. Должны получить запись с id = 2.

2.Получаем массив - ["one", "two", "three"]. Должны получить записи с id =7,8

3.Получаем массив - ["one", "three"]. Должны получить записи с id = 7,8,9

Ссылка на fiddle - [ТЫК](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e668c81704b1d8464e54dab10fbbcd09)

Пример моей реализации на стеке NestJS + TypeORM + MySQL v8.0

```js
async test12(
    title: string,
    entityType: CompetenceSearchType,
  ): Promise<
    { competencies: Record<string, number> }[] | { competence: Competence }[]
  > {
    const res = [] as Array<{ competencies: Record<string, number> }>;

    if (entityType === CompetenceSearchType.ACTIVITY) {
      const all: Array<Activity> = [];
      const [entities, count] = await this.activityRepository.findAndCount({
        where: {
          competencies: Raw(() => {
            return `competencies->"$.${title}" > 0`;
          }),
        },
      });

      entities.map(entity => {
        if (!res.includes(entity)) {
          res.push(entity);
        }
      });
    }
    return res;
  }
```

Формат записей в поле competence такой: {"ключ": 1} - Строка - это ключ, значение - число. Может хранится несколько значений.
Если перебирать циклом, то появляются дубли и он все равно ищет только по 1 ключу, но задать несколько условий поиска я не могу, так-как не могу знать, сколько получу ключей.

```html
CREATE TABLE `activity` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `createdAt` datetime(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
  `deletedAt` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `private` tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `topic` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `authorId` int NOT NULL,
  `startDate` datetime NOT NULL,
  `endDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `location` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `competencies` json DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK_0e60c1982a77d3e092ef4f3bef9` (`authorId`) /* ,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_0e60c1982a77d3e092ef4f3bef9` FOREIGN KEY (`authorId`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE 
                                                    */
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

```html
INSERT INTO `activity` VALUES 
(1,'testActivity123','2021-06-21 05:14:44.644150',NULL,0,NULL,NULL,18,'2021-06-21 05:14:45',NULL,NULL,'{\"Test activityCompetence for createCompetence\": 1}'),
(2,'testActivity123','2021-06-21 05:14:44.644150',NULL,0,NULL,NULL,18,'2021-06-21 05:14:45',NULL,NULL,'{\"Test\": 3}'),
(3,'testActivity123','2021-06-21 05:14:44.644000',NULL,0,NULL,NULL,18,'2021-06-21 05:14:45',NULL,NULL,'{\"Test activityCompetence for createCompetence\": 1}'),
(4,'test','2021-06-21 05:30:29.686046',NULL,0,NULL,NULL,51,'2021-06-21 05:30:30',NULL,NULL,'{\"competenceForSearch\": 20, \"blabla text\": 2}'),
(5,'test','2021-06-21 05:30:29.686046',NULL,0,NULL,NULL,51,'2021-06-21 05:30:30',NULL,NULL,'{\"firstCompetence\": 2, \"fourthCompetence\": 4}'),
(6,'test','2021-06-21 05:30:29.686046',NULL,0,NULL,NULL,51,'2021-06-21 05:30:30',NULL,NULL,'{\"firstCompetence\": 2, \"secondCompetence\": 2}'),
(7,'test','2021-06-21 05:30:29.686046',NULL,0,NULL,NULL,51,'2021-06-21 05:30:30',NULL,NULL,'{\"one\": 1, \"two\": 2, \"three\": 3}'),
(8,'test','2021-06-21 05:30:29.686046',NULL,0,NULL,NULL,51,'2021-06-21 05:30:30',NULL,NULL,'{\"one\": 1, \"two\": 2, \"three\": 3, \"four\": 4}'),
(9,'test','2021-06-21 05:30:29.686046',NULL,0,NULL,NULL,51,'2021-06-21 05:30:30',NULL,NULL,'{\"one\": 1, \"four\": 4, \"three\": 3}');
```

Comment: Не понял... это вот Вы серьёзно - затащить к себе на клиента весь массив данных, а потом фильтровать нужное? Куда как проще отдать на MySQL критерий и получить уже отфильтрованные по нему записи.

Comment: Хорошо, не подскажете, как тогда это можно реализовать, если неизвестно, сколько критериев для фильтрации у меня будет? Я могу сортировать по 1 ключу, а могу и по нескольким.  Идея такова, что при сортировке по нескольким ключам, ищутся те записи, где они все имеются.

Comment: Вы для начала определитесь, нужен поиск или нужна сортировка. Это как бы не одно и то же.

Comment: *как тогда это можно реализовать, если неизвестно, сколько критериев для фильтрации у меня будет?* На момент, когда уже надо получить данные, их количество и значения известны, верно? Если решите идти по пути фильтрации на сервере - выкладывайте исходные данные. CREATE TABLE таблицы, в которой нужно выполнять поиск, пример данных в виде INSERT INTO (3-5 записей), пример набора критериев для фильтрации и требуемый ответ для этих данных. Ну и укажите точную версию MySQL.

Comment: Нужен поиск. Да, на сервер приходит массив строк, длину соответственно могу узнать Версия Mysql 8.0 Добавил sql запросы

Comment: *Добавил sql запросы* Они же в виде [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=906fd30370972c556d7a040fb11d24a9). Теперь дайте критерий (скажем, 2 ключа) и требуемый результат для него. Да, поправьте fiddle (добавьте ещё записей - а то выбирать из 3 записей, 2 из которых дубликаты, по 2 критериям - хрень получится) и вставьте ссылку в текст вопроса.

Comment: Обновил шапку вопроса

Comment: То есть Вам нужно множественное совпадение - в JSON должны присутствовать все переданные в качестве фильтра ключи. Так?

Comment: Да. Каждое значение должно присутствовать в JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT activity.id
FROM activity
CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(@criteria,
                      '$[*]' COLUMNS (keyname VARCHAR(255) PATH '$')) jsontable
GROUP BY activity.id
HAVING !SUM(JSON_EXTRACT(activity.competencies, CONCAT('$.', jsontable.keyname)) IS NULL)
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=78de055fd75554a5266c5afda2ce402a

Требуемый набор фильтров передаётся как JSON-массив (у меня - в переменной `@criteria`).

Поиск - регистрозависимый (см. последний блок кода). Что неудивительно, ибо JSON имеет binary collation.